# What is the alternate for Datastax cassandra core driver DataType serialize/deserialize methods

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

We are using scala code run jobs from spark(1.5.2) which connects to cassandra. The new spark-cassandra-connector(1.5) depends on cassandra-driver-core-2.2.0-RC3.

DataType serialize/deserialize methods removed in 2.2.0-RC3.

What is the alternate way to serialize/deserialize?

```
13: error: value serialize is not a member of com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.CollectionType
[ERROR]       implicit def ListString2ByteBuffer(list : List[String]): ByteBuffer = 
DataType.list(DataType.text()).serialize(list.asJava, ProtocolVersion.NEWEST_SUPPORTED);
```

Comment: Check this link: https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/deprecated-list.html

Comment: Hi Ravindra, The deprecated list shows the second parameter of serialize/deserialize is changed from int type to enum , and marked the old ones deprecated

Comment: I have used jackson API with objectMapper to serialize and deserialize. is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

See: [Upgrade guide](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/upgrade_guide/)

"DataType has no more references to TypeCodec, so methods that dealt with serialization and deserialization of data types have been removed... These methods must now be invoked on TypeCodec directly."

To obtain TypeCodec you can use something like that:

```
CodecRegistry.DEFAULT_INSTANCE.codecFor(myDateType)
```